# PL/SQL string tasks

Tags: sql, oracle, string, plsql

I need to work on two tasks in PL/SQL:

1. Is to display the first characters of each word in the string e.g. "Standard Query Language", so it should return value as "SQL".
2. converting text "apple" to upper caps "APPLE", but not using the upper case or lower case predefined functions.

is it possible in PL/SQL, by not using advanced level functions but just beginner level approach.

Comment: For what version of Oracle?  10g+ supports regex. And why can you not use UPPER?  Must be homework...

Comment: yes its 10g, well its not a homework, its for getting idea that if functions like UPPER doesn't exits then how will do it in PL/SQL, as I know how to do above in JAVA but don't know the way in PL/SQL. Can't use REGEX as still me going through basic PL/SQL

Comment: You could use [TRANSLATE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) to drive to upper or lower case, but what's the point of using existing functionality while ignoring others?

Comment: @kaibuki. Can you give an example of when UPPER will not be available?

Comment: @carpenteri: I suppose the only case where UPPER is unavailable would be for pl/sql homework :)

Comment: REGEX is built in to Oracle's SQL engine. Why can't you use it?

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat - Thanks I thought I was missing something! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the code for performing the both tasks mentioned above, they work fine, haven't added exception handling or validation.

```
(1) DECLARE
    NAME VARCHAR2(100):='&NAM';
    CURR_CHAR VARCHAR2(1);
    ABBRV VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
ABBRV := SUBSTR(NAME,1,1);
FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(NAME) LOOP
    CURR_CHAR := SUBSTR(NAME,I,1);
    IF CURR_CHAR =  CHR(32) THEN
        -- &PL('SPACE');
        ABBRV := ABBRV || SUBSTR(NAME,I+1,1);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
&PL('ABBRIVATION OF : ' || NAME);
&PL(' IS ... :  ' || ABBRV);
END;
```

---

```
(2)DECLARE
    VALUE VARCHAR2(100) := '&VAL';
    CURR_CHAR VARCHAR2(1);
    UPPER_CASE VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(VALUE) LOOP
        CURR_CHAR := SUBSTR(VALUE,I,1);
        UPPER_CASE := UPPER_CASE || CHR(ASCII(CURR_CHAR)-32);   
    END LOOP;
    &PL(' UPPER CASE : ' || UPPER_CASE);
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many things are possible in PL/SQL, but in general if you can do it in SQL then don't reinvent built-in functionality using a procedural approach (regex as OMG Ponies commented would probably be a good approach here).

That said, if you *really* wanted to iterate over a string char by char, you can probably do something like:

```
declare
  in_string varchar2(20) := 'Im a string';
  in_length number;
  cnt number := 0;
  in_char char(1);
begin
  in_length := length(in_string);
  while (cnt < in_length)
  loop
    cnt := cnt + 1;
    in_char := substr(in_string, cnt, 1);
    -- do something wonderful here

  end loop;
exception
  when others then raise;
end;
```

But again, don't do this to uppercase a string (for example) if you can just use the UPPER function ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd drop the "exception when others then raise" section. This only achieves obscuring the line number where a real error took place.

Comment: it was a simple example, but if you want a "stack trace" (or close to it for Oracle anyway), then I'd use dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace.  I would not skip raising exceptions though.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), I would INITCAP

```
select initcap (lower('Structured query Language'))
from dual
```

Then iterate through the string looking for those uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions to the rescue!

To extract the first character of each word:

```
select regexp_replace ('Structured Query Language', ' \*(.)[^ ]\*', '\1' ) from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Is to display the first characters of each word in the string e.g. "Standard Query          Language", so it should return value as "SQL".

   ```
   DECLARE
       STR VARCHAR(100):='Standard Query Language';
       J NUMBER;
   BEGIN
       FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(STR) LOOP        
           IF SUBSTR(STR,I,1)=' ' THEN
               J:=I+1;
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(SUBSTR(STR,J,1));
           END IF;
           IF I=1 THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(SUBSTR(STR,I,1));
           END IF;
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
   END;
   ```
2. converting text "apple" to upper caps "APPLE", but not using the upper case or lower case predefined functions.

   ```
   DECLARE
       STR VARCHAR2(10):='kiran';
   BEGIN
       FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(STR) LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(CHR(ASCII(SUBSTR(STR,I,1))-32));
       END LOOP;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
   END;
   ```