# PL/SQL Sort a varchar2 variable

Tags: plsql

Is there a way to easily sort a varchar2 variable in PL/SQL please?  For example to get the result 'ABC' using variable 'BAC'?  I assume there isn't something along the lines of:

```
v_text := SORT(v_text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select listagg(substr(v_text,level,1)) within group 
  (order by substr(v_text,level,1)) into v_text 
  from dual connect by level<=length(v_text);
```

Comment: Blink blink! That is a cool solution. Totally unreadable, but very good!

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you ever so much.  So much for me to learn in so little code!  Thanks again - your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way as far as I can tell. This is what you can do:

1. Iterate over the `varchar` `char` by `char`. Use something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866430/993547).
2. Create two arrays, one 'old', one 'new'.
3. Fill the 'old' array with the result of 1.
4. Then use a sort algorithm to put the sorted values in 'new'.